# issue on scrollable table

Tags: html, css

I have a code to display the content of table as scrollable. But i am not sure on how to do scroll only on body not with head. Currently it happening for whole table.

Please help me.

```css
tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  height: 300px;
  /* Just for the demo          */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th> SLno</th>
    <th>Item name</th>
    <th>Item code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>icecream</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>biscuits</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Move table head in `thead` and table body in `tbody`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for fixed headers on a window adjustable table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249385/looking-for-fixed-headers-on-a-window-adjustable-table)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need your `thead` of the `table` to be separate from the rest of your `table` by either applying `position: relative;` or `absolute`.

Apply `display: block` to your `tbody` so that you have a block level element which you can then apply `height` and `overflow` properties to have a desirable scrollable table.

Refer code:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/*thead*/

thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  width: 700px;
  overflow: visible;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 36px;
  min-height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {
  /*first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #88b;
}


/*tbody*/

tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  height: 239px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: #bbc;
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 36px;
  min-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Town</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th>Anual Income</th>
        <th>Matital Status</th>
        <th>Children</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Smith</td>
        <td>Macelsfield</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>Brewer</td>
        <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenny Jones</td>
        <td>Threlkeld</td>
        <td>Cumbria</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Shepherdess</td>
        <td>£28,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter Frampton</td>
        <td>Avebury</td>
        <td>Wiltshire</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>Musician</td>
        <td>£124,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Simon King</td>
        <td>Malvern</td>
        <td>Worchestershire</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>Naturalist</td>
        <td>£65,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lucy Diamond</td>
        <td>St Albans</td>
        <td>Hertfordshire</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>Pharmasist</td>
        <td>Retired</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Austin Stevenson</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>Lothian</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Vigilante</td>
        <td>£86,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wilma Rubble</td>
        <td>Bedford</td>
        <td>Bedfordshire</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>Housewife</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kat Dibble</td>
        <td>Manhattan</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>Policewoman</td>
        <td>$36,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Henry Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Lincolnshire</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Landowner</td>
        <td>Lots</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alan Brisingamen</td>
        <td>Alderley</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>352</td>
        <td>Arcanist</td>
        <td>A pile of gems</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```